# GitHub: move issue comments to different issues

Tags: github, issue-tracking

A user posted a comment to an existing issue on one of my GitHub repos and his comment should really have been added as a new issue. There is now a whole mini-thread that is misplaced. Is there any way to move these comments to a different issue? I've seen a number of questions on moving issues amongst GitHub repos, etc, but haven't been able to find anything on moving comments.

Comment: This would be a great feature, avoids topic-tainting.

Comment: Found this question looking for exactly this feature and it apparently doesn't exist. You can open a new issue while quoting a comment, but that doesn't move/remove the misplaced thread.  I'd suggest "new issue from comment" and then a comment redirecting "further discussion" there.

Answer (score 2):

You can "Reference in new issue" clicking on the "..." button of the comments, then create a new issue with these comments and continue on it.

It's not perfect but it could help moving the discussion elsewhere.